# Expectation of standard deviation

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, moment-generating-functions

The moment generating function of a gamma random variable is $M_X(t)=(1-t/\beta)^{-\alpha}$, we have
$E[X]=\alpha/\beta$

$E[X^2]=\frac{\alpha(\alpha+1)}{\beta^2}$

$E[X^3]=\frac{\alpha(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)}{\beta^3}$

$E[X^4]=\frac{\alpha(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)(\alpha+3)}{\beta^4}$

and $M_{\bar{X}}(t)=(1-\frac{1}{n\beta}t)^{-n\alpha}$, gives

$E[\bar{X}]=\alpha/\beta$

$E[\bar{X}^2]=\frac{\alpha(\alpha+\frac{1}{n})}{\beta^2}$

$E[\bar{X}^3]=\frac{\alpha(\alpha+\frac{1}{n})(\alpha+\frac{2}{n})}{\beta^3}$

$E[\bar{X}^4]=\frac{\alpha(\alpha+\frac{1}{n})(\alpha+\frac{2}{n})(\alpha+\frac{3}{n})}{\beta^4}$

By using the above identities, we obtain

$E[S^4]=\frac{\alpha}{\beta^4(n-1)^2}\bigg[(n^2-1)\alpha+6(\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})^2\bigg]$.

I want to find $var(S^2)$, where $S$ is standard deviation. But i don't how to find $E[S^4]$.

Comment: I misread the question, so I deleted my answer. I think this page:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVarianceDistribution.html

Gives a good detailed description for how to calculate the variance of the sample variance. I don't want to write out the algebra, because, as noted in that link, it's tedious.

Comment: Are the data $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma)?$ If so, then $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2 \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(n-1),$ where $S^2$ is sample variance.